# Question about pure tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose that $A$ is a unital algebra over the field $k$ and $a \in A$ satisfies

$$\forall x \in A: \exists z_x\in A: x \otimes a = z_x \otimes 1$$

Can we conclude that $a \in k1$?

It seems plausible, but strange things can happen when considering tensor products! I tried to do a functional trick but could not conclude.

Comment: What multiple of $1$? Clearly $a = a\cdot 1$. Which "strange things" can happen to tensor products? And what is a "functional trick"?

Comment: Just to dot i's and cross t's: By "$a$ is a multiple of $1$", you mean that $a$ belongs to the base field $k$? And your tensor product is over $k$?

Comment: @peterag Yes, sorry. I meant scalar multiple, not multiple in the algebra. And yes, the tensor product is taken over the field $k$.

Comment: Presumably $a=z_11$.

Comment: Yes I don't see what the issue is. The condition is that if you tensor $a$ by anything the tensor is in $k$. Then tensor with $x=1$ and it is done.

Comment: I cannot see why this should be true, even though I don't have an example in mind. Maybe we can have $z_x=ax$ and $a\not\in k.$ Imagine $x,a \in M(n,k)$ and $a$ a diagonal matrix with at least two different entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x=1$, we know that $1 \otimes a=b \otimes 1$ for some $b \in A$.

Let $e_i$ be any basis of $A$ containing $1$ (say $e_t=1$), then $(e_i \otimes e_j)$ is a basis of $A \otimes A$. Write $a=\sum_i{a_ie_i},b=\sum_i{b_ie_i}$. Then $1 \otimes a=\sum_i{a_i e_t \otimes e_i}$ and $b \otimes 1=\sum_i{b_ie_i \otimes e_t}$. By identifying coordinates, since $1 \otimes a=b \otimes 1$, it follows that $a_i=0$ if $i \neq t$, so $a=a_te_t \in k1_A$.